# Excel - Copy data from one cell to another if check mark using button

Tags: excel, if-statement, button, copy

I have an excel workbook.  In this workbook, I have 5 worksheets.

1 = List A

2 = List B

3 = List C

4 = List D

5 = Order form

My lists worksheets will be setup like this.  Col A = Checkbox.  Col B = Number.  Col C = Description.

My end goal is to have a check box next to each item in each list.  From here, I will go through each list and select the items from the list I want.  Once I have chosen all of my items, I go to "Order Form" and on this worksheet is a button that I click.  When I click this button, it will copy the data from Col B ONLY if there is a check mark in Col A in all the worksheets.

So, if I check A2, A4, A10, & A15 on List A and check A3, A9, & A22 on List B, and A35 on List C, when I click the button on "Order Form", the data from 'List A'!B2, 'List A'!B4, 'List A'!B10, 'List A'!B15, 'List B'!B3,  'List B'!B9, 'List B'!B22, and 'List C'!B35 get copied to 'Order Form'!E22:E30

This will need to be dynamic, since I may only check 2 items, or I may check 30.

****************EDIT******************

As I commented, I believe I have solved this issue, but I am always looking for ways to make it better

This is my VBA code to execute in my excel workbook:

```
Private Sub Load_Order_Click()
' Setup Data
    Dim Last_Row0 As Long
    Dim ws0 As Worksheet
    Set ws0 = Sheets("work")

' Sort and Copy Data from each page to Work
With Sheets("1 - Conduit")
    .Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
    .Range("a2", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
    End With
With Sheets("work")
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
With Sheets("2 - Elbows")
    .Range("A:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="x"
    .Range("a2", .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
    End With
With Sheets("work")
    Last_Row0 = ws0.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & Last_Row0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

' Not Sure
With Sheets("1 - Conduit")
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").AutoFilter
    End With
With Sheets("2 - Elbows")
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:C").AutoFilter
    End With

' Clear Selection Marks
Sheets("1 - Conduit").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Sheets("2 - Elbows").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select
Selection.ClearContents

' Show all
Sheets("1 - Conduit").Activate
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Sheets("2 - Elbows").Activate
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

' Copy BMC numbers from work page to Order Template
Sheets("work").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B200").Copy
Sheets("Order").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("E22").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

' Clear work page
Sheets("work").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A:F").Select
Selection.ClearContents

' Return to Order page
Sheets("Order").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    End Sub

Private Sub Print_Order_Click()
' Print Order form to PDF
Sheets("Order").Activate
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="Material Order"
End Sub
```

The end goal is this.  Worksheets 1 - Conduit, 2 - Elbows, etc (this cam be upwards of 30 worksheets to go through) will be scanned.  On each worksheet Col "A" is the "check box" column (for now I am using an 'x').  If an item has an 'x' in col A, it copies col A & B to a worksheet called "work".  I did this to be able to sort and stack as needed.  Then, once all the worksheets have been checked, it goes back and clears all of the 'x' in Col A on all worksheets.  Once that is done, it goes and copies Col B from "work" (the REAL data I need), and copies it to a specific range on a worksheet called "Order".  Then, once the data has been copied to "Order", it goes and clears out "work".

This code functions.  It does what I want it to do.  My next step is to see how to make is simpler.  In C++, I would use a while or a for loop and have it step through a sequence, but I don't know if that is possible here.

Comment: Instead of using an object, like a tick mark/check box, what if the user simply put an "x" in the cell next to the item?  That way you could then filter, or more easily see what info you want copied.

Comment: I am not opposed to that.  And that may be the way to start.

Comment: having an "x" or checkboxes could be the same though, since the "true" value of each checkbox is a boolean value in a linked cell... well, you need to do this via formula or VBA?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sample file/data for this case? | Plus, if you had tried something and it didn't work..please share it too. | It'll greatly increase the Q clarity/scope. ( :

Comment: I don't mind at all.  I think I have it fixed, but I am always looking to make my code better.  I'll comment below so i can give more detail.